# SessionTimeout value store in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session-timeout

We have a need for having different sessiontimeouts for different departments or roles etc. Is it possible to reset sessiontimeout and make it as a input field entry by the user and store it in database? So the session timeout must maintain its values from the database?
We can set sessiontimeout in web.config file, but this is a dynamic scenario different for different users/departments.
Any suggestions would be good! I am using asp.net mvc5 and sql server2012

Thanks